# Number of qubits and breaking hashes

Tags: hash, post-quantum-cryptography

Noting [D-Wave's press release](http://www.dwavesys.com/press-releases/d-wave-systems-breaks-1000-qubit-quantum-computing-barrier) on a 1000 qubits quantum computer had me wondering...

Does the number of qubits nonlinearly change the speed/rate at breaking a SHA256 hash?

If someone makes a say 10,000 qubit processor, does this speed up cracking the hash more than 10 times (linearly) faster?

Comment: You should be aware that D-Wave builds quantum annealing computers which are no quantum computers in the sense needed to do cryptanalysis faster than classically. Otherwise, yes, you can get a linear speed-up. See: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25168/can-grovers-algorithm-be-parallelized

Comment: Quantum computers reduce preimage resistance of an $n$ bit hash to $n/2$ bits. Depending on the cost model, they either reduce collision cost from $n/3$ bits or don't reduce it at all.

Comment: Snake oil with traces of antibiotics doesn't make it the new wonder-drug. There is yet to find *any* problem, where D-Wave is actually faster than state-of-the-art classical algorithms.